# Retrieving data from stored procedure (msql) in Java

Tags: java, sql-server, stored-procedures, jdbc

I have this stored procedure in sql server:

```
create procedure [dbo].[prSum]

AS
    create table @SUM (
         ClientName Varchar(40), 
         SearchDoc Varchar(20), 
         SearchName Varchar(20), 
    )
    --each one of this procedures returns a query with the same colunms size of @SUM
    insert into @SUM exec pr1
    insert into @SUM exec pr2
    insert into @SUM exec pr3
    insert into @SUM exec pr4
    insert into @SUM exec pr5

RETURN Select * from @SUM
GO
```

In SSMS I can run:

```
exec prSum
```

And the Select * from @SUM is displayed.

But I trying get this on my java class with jdbc:

```
package calc;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class ConnectURL {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://######;databaseName=####;user=#####;password=###;

        try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl); Statement stmt = con.createStatement();) {
            String SQL = "{ call dbo.prSum}";
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(SQL);

            while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println(rs.getString("ClientName"));
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Getting and getting this:

com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The statement did not return a result set.

Comment: Add `SET NOCOUNT ON;` to the beginning of your stored procedure.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. That can't possibly be your stored procedure because there are multiple syntax errors. You don't create a table variable, you declare it. And the RETURN statement from a stored procedure returns an int. You can not use it to return a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your stored procedure has numerous issues.  But as written *in fact* doesn't return any data. You are RETURNing before sending results to the client.

Should be something like:

```
create procedure [dbo].[prSum]

AS
begin
    set nocount on;
    declare @SUM table (
         ClientName Varchar(40), 
         SearchDoc Varchar(20), 
         SearchName Varchar(20)
    )
    --each one of this procedures returns a query with the same colunms size of @SUM
    insert into @SUM exec pr1;
    insert into @SUM exec pr2;
    insert into @SUM exec pr3;
    insert into @SUM exec pr4;
    insert into @SUM exec pr5;

    Select * from @SUM;
    return;
end
GO
```

Comment: Thank you, I am new with sql server and I was trying with temp tables and variables, so I mess up creating the post. My problem was the "SET NOCOUNT ON;" that was missing.